# Circular dependency even though classes are forward declared

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, circular-dependency

There is this really weird issue, where even forward declaring the affected classes won't work to resolve the circular dependency.

As you can see, both classes are forward declared. So is there any explaination? No symbols of either class get defined. It clearly is a circular dependency error.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

**LogBackend.h**

```
#ifndef LOGGER_BACKEND_H
#define LOGGER_BACKEND_H

#include "Logger.h"
#include <string>

namespace se {
    class Logger;
    class LogBackend {
    public:

        LogBackend() { }
        explicit LogBackend(const std::string& name);
        virtual ~LogBackend() { }

        virtual void log(const Logger::Level l, const std::string& text) = 0;

        /*
         Method interface
        */

        bool valid();
        std::string getName();

    protected:
        bool m_valid = true;
        std::string m_name;
    };
}
#endif
```

*Notice: There are derived classes of LogBackend*

**Logger.h**

```
#ifndef LOGGER_H
#define LOGGER_H

#include "LogBackend.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <glew/glew.h>

namespace se {
    class LogBackend;
    class Logger {
    public:

        enum class Level { WARNING, INFO, EXCEPTION, SEVERE };
        static std::string to_string(Level l);

        static void add(const LogBackend& backend);

        /*
         Methods
        */

    private:
        static std::vector<LogBackend> m_backends;
    };
}
#endif
```

Comment: You know a `std::vector<LogBackend>` can't contain subclasses of `LogBackend`, right?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that strictly speaking if you have first `#include "foo.h"` and then `class foo;` it is not a forward declaration.

Comment: `std::vector<LogBackend>` since it's an abstract class. You can contain a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<LogBackend>>` instead

Comment: Oopsie... It should have been LogBackend* all along.
Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using, in Logger.h a `std::vector<LogBackend>` a forward declaration is not enough, unless you change it to `std::vector<LogBackend *>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<LogBackend>>`

LogBackend has a similar problem, you are using Logger::Level, which is not available since you simply forward declared Logger.

I suggest you to break the dependency in Logger.h by making use just of a pointer to LogBackend

Comment: Works, thanks! But in my case it was easier to factor out Level into a seperate header file.

Answer (score 1):

You've fooled yourself by adding those forward references. The underlying problem is that LogBackend.h has `#include "Logger.h"` and Logger.h has `#include "LogBackend.h"`. The include guards prevent infinite recursion, but that also means that when the compiler sees `#include "Logger.h"` in a source file it tries to compile "Logger.h", which includes "LogBackend.h", which includes "Logger.h", which is empty because of the include guards. **That** is the cycle that you have to break, and that's a matter of thinking carefully about what needs what so that you can have classes that are linearly dependent instead of circularly, which will make it possible for your headers to be linearly dependent instead of circularly.

Comment: Thanks, this got me thinking.
By making a linear structure (factoring out Level) I broke the circle. But is there a techinque (no explaination needed, just a keyword) if they NEED to be circularly dependend?

Comment: Often you can define both classes in the same header by starting out with a forward declaration of the second one, then defining the first, then defining the second. If the interfaces of the two classes in fact each depend on contents of the other then you've got an intractable situation.